# Something like first Betti number that is $-1$ for a $2$-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, math-history, betti-numbers

I told some advanced high-school students informally about homology (i.e. the "number of holes" in a space, by which I really mean the first Betti number), and one of them seemed to think that the homology of a $2$-sphere was $-1$. Their justification was that if you "add a hole" then you get a disc, which has zero holes, and therefore the original sphere must have one less than zero holes.

This student says that they have heard this somewhere, so I imagine they are referring to some related or historical construction. Does anyone know what they were likely referring to?

Comment: Deleting a point from $S^2$ gives (via, for example, stereographic projection) an open disk.

Comment: @anomaly Yeah I understand the student's argument. My point is that they seem to be referring to a concept that exists and has a name (i.e. some invariant of the space that is $-1$ in the case of a sphere), and I would like to know what that name is

Comment: They probably got it from this Matt Parker video: https://youtu.be/ymF1bp-qrjU

Answer (score 0):

If you want to think of both steps in  $3$-disk $\leadsto$ $2$-sphere $\leadsto$ $2$-disk as adding holes then you can only keep invariant the parity of the number of holes. In that case, Euler characteristic mod $2$ (which of course is the same as sum of Betti numbers mod $2$) is what you're looking for. If you are happy with saying that "an odd-dimensional hole cancels out an even-dimensional hole" then the Euler characteristic is a refinement. You can take negative reduced (as in reduced homology) Euler characteristic if you want it to match the number for the $2$-sphere and disk with finitely many punctures.